# What is the value of electroweak scale? Depends on literature?

Tags: standard-model, definition, electroweak, order-of-magnitude

Depending on the literature, we see for the electroweak scale the following typical values :
100 GeV, 125 GeV (Higgs mass), 246 GeV (vev), 1 TeV

So what is really the value of electroweak scale?

Comment: People speak loosely, but a formula explains all. Go to your sources (and cite them) and specify what each says. The PDG uses $v\sim 246$GeV, and that's that. If you catch *anyone* using the *logically independent* Higgs mass as "the electroweak scale", toss his writings in the trash and walk away with extreme prejudice, of course.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos : all right, thank you

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566212/electroweak-unification-and-electroweak-scale).